# Hide product price from wishlist in magento2

Tags: magento2, product, price, wishlist

How can I hide price based on a condition from customer wishlist products.

```
<block class="Magento\Wishlist\Block\Customer\Wishlist" name="customer.wishlist" template="Magento_Wishlist::view.phtml" cacheable="false">
                <block class="Magento\Wishlist\Block\Rss\Link" name="wishlist.rss.link" template="Magento_Wishlist::rss/wishlist.phtml"/>
                <block class="Magento\Wishlist\Block\Customer\Wishlist\Items" name="customer.wishlist.items" as="items" template="Magento_Wishlist::item/list.phtml" cacheable="false">
                    <block class="Magento\Wishlist\Block\Customer\Wishlist\Item\Column\Image" name="customer.wishlist.item.image" template="Magento_Wishlist::item/column/image.phtml" cacheable="false"/>
                    <block class="Magento\Wishlist\Block\Customer\Wishlist\Item\Column\Info" name="customer.wishlist.item.name" template="Magento_Wishlist::item/column/name.phtml" cacheable="false"/>
                    <block class="Magento\Wishlist\Block\Customer\Wishlist\Item\Column\Cart" name="customer.wishlist.item.price" template="Magento_Wishlist::item/column/price.phtml" cacheable="false">
                        <block class="Magento\Catalog\Pricing\Render" name="product.price.render.wishlist">
                            <arguments>
                                *<argument name="price_render" xsi:type="string">product.price.render.default</argument>*
                                <argument name="price_type_code" xsi:type="string">wishlist_configured_price</argument>
                                <argument name="price_label" xsi:type="boolean">false</argument>
                                <argument name="zone" xsi:type="string">item_list</argument>
                            </arguments>
                        </block>
                        <block class="Magento\Wishlist\Block\Customer\Wishlist\Item\Options" name="customer.wishlist.item.options" cacheable="false"/>
                    </block>
                    <block class="Magento\Wishlist\Block\Customer\Wishlist\Item\Column\Actions" name="customer.wishlist.item.inner" template="Magento_Wishlist::item/column/actions.phtml" cacheable="false">
                        <arguments>
                            <argument name="css_class" xsi:type="string">product-item-inner</argument>
                        </arguments>
                        <block class="Magento\Wishlist\Block\Customer\Wishlist\Item\Column\Comment" name="customer.wishlist.item.comment" template="Magento_Wishlist::item/column/comment.phtml" cacheable="false">
                            <arguments>
                                <argument name="title" translate="true" xsi:type="string">Product Details and Comment</argument>
                            </arguments>
                        </block>
                        <block class="Magento\Wishlist\Block\Customer\Wishlist\Item\Column\Cart" name="customer.wishlist.item.cart" template="Magento_Wishlist::item/column/cart.phtml" cacheable="false">
                            <arguments>
                                <argument name="title" translate="true" xsi:type="string">Add to Cart</argument>
                            </arguments>
                        </block>

                        <block class="Magento\Wishlist\Block\Customer\Wishlist\Item\Column\Actions" name="customer.wishlist.item.actions" template="Magento_Wishlist::item/column/actions.phtml" cacheable="false">
                            <arguments>
                                <argument name="css_class" xsi:type="string">product-item-actions</argument>
                            </arguments>
                            <block class="Magento\Wishlist\Block\Customer\Wishlist\Item\Column\Edit" name="customer.wishlist.item.edit" template="Magento_Wishlist::item/column/edit.phtml" before="-" cacheable="false"/>
                            <block class="Magento\Wishlist\Block\Customer\Wishlist\Item\Column\Remove" name="customer.wishlist.item.remove" template="Magento_Wishlist::item/column/remove.phtml" cacheable="false"/>
                        </block>
                    </block>
                </block>
```

**Need to override for this** `<argument name="price_render" xsi:type="string">product.price.render.default</argument>`

Comment: What your condition where you where you want to hide price product page listing page and or somewhere else?

Answer (score 0):

Create **wishlist_index_index.xml** file under your module, **view/frontend/layout/wishlist_index_index.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <referenceBlock name="product.price.render.wishlist" remove='true' />
    </body>
</page>
```

Comment: I want to hide based on product attribute